# Are configuration files usually sensitive to trailing whitespace

Tags: configuration, whitespace

I was trying to configure LightDM. It appears that `lightdm.conf` is sensitive to trailing spaces. I found that I get different behavior with

`greeter-hide-users=true`

and

`greeter-hide-users=true`

where the second has a trailing space. Without the space, the greeter hides the list of users as I expected. With the space, the greeter displays the list of users as if the `greeter-hide-users` parameter is not set to true.

I am thinking of reporting this as a bug, but I want to make sure this type of sensitivity to trailing spaces is not typical in configuration files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the configuration, `/etc/passwd` for example can be whitespace sensitive, because then you've set a user's shell to `/bin/tcsh` and then they cannot login because `/bin/tcsh` does not exist. This can also be difficult to debug; logging should ideally quote or bracket things so the logs have `'/bin/tcsh '` or `[username ]` in them, and looking at the data with a hex viewer (`hexdump`, `xxd`) can by handy.

Eliminating trailing whitespace by default should be sensible and safe. (Um, except for the trailing newline, which it is *not* sensible to remove from the end of a file.)

Comment: This is true. Syntax depends on the program which is parsing the configuration file, therefore, it depends on the configuration.